# In Bayesian Ridge Regression, is the ridge regression parameter $\lambda$ treated as random?

Tags: bayesian, ridge-regression

I am having a hard time understanding the Bayesian Ridge Regression.

In Bayesian Ridge Regression, is the ridge regression parameter $\lambda$ treated as random? or do we treat the $\lambda$ as given?

Thank you,

Comment: not random, parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bayesian approach we treat *every* parameter as a random variable and define a prior for it. The prior is defined in terms of some parameters, e.g. $\boldsymbol{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1})$, where the parameters of the priors are either chosen in advance, or we assume priors for them as well, and estimate them from the data.